# vue js-amchart couldn't rerendered and dont show second chart data

Tags: data-binding, vuejs3, amcharts, amcharts5

I'm new in vue3 and I have a component with two chart that create with amchart but one of my chart couldn't be re-render. actually At any moment, only one of the charts has data and the second chart is not re-rendered and my dounat cahrt doesnt show data

```js
getDonutChart() {
    this.donutCharts = [];

    const donutBasketComposition = {
      basketId: this.selectedBasket?.id,
      isAggregate: this.selectedBasket?.isAggregate,
      basketComposition:basketCompositionEnum.donutChart,
      startDateStr: this.selectedBasket?.startDateStr,
    } as any;

    this.dashboardService.getBasketComposition(donutBasketComposition)
      .then((data: Response<Array<DounatChartResultDto>>) => {
        this.hideMultiLoading();
        if (data.status == ResponseStatuses.Success) {
          
          this.donutReRender++;
          data.data.forEach((item) => {
            this.donutCharts.push({
              title: item.title,
              value: item.amount
            } as DonutChartDto)
          })
        }
        })
  
  }
  
  
  
  
   getBasketComposition() { 
    this.displayChartBarsAsset = [];
    this.displayChartBarsAsset.length = 0;


    


    const basketComposition = {
      basketId: this.selectedBasket?.id,
      isAggregate: this.selectedBasket?.isAggregate,
      basketComposition:type,
      startDateStr: this.selectedBasket?.startDateStr,
    } as any;

    if (hasItem) {
      this.displayChartBarsAsset = this.setChartModel(hasItem.data);
      this.reRenderCustomeChart++;
    } else {
      this.showMultiLoading();
      this.dashboardService?.getBasketComposition(basketComposition)
        .then((data: Response<Array<basketCompositionDto>>) => {
          this.reRenderCustomeChart++;
        this.displayChartBarsAsset = this.setChartModel(data?.data);
        this.listHistories.push({ model: basketComposition, data: data?.data })
        this.hideMultiLoading();

      })

    }
```

```html
<donut-chart :donutdata="donutCharts" :key="donutReRender" />
<custome-chart :chartData="displayChartBarsAsset" :key="reRenderCustomeChart" />
```